# VSTS work item transition on Build

Tags: tfs-workitem

I'm currently using Team Foundation Server 2008 as a source control and build engine.
When I checkin some changes and associate the change with a work item the work item flow I've defined changed the status from active to ready for test. Unfortunately this is not accurate as it's not actually ready for test until a build is completed. Is there any way to make it so that a build can change the status of work items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a custom task in MSBuild that allows you to update a work item. You could easily write one though. See this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130320%28VS.80%29.aspx

This one show you how to write a task
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx